my svg is 0x0 when I use the <use href> function to open a svg file inside html
My problem is that the SVG size is 0 x 0 inside my browser.
I use the following HTML code:
<span class="service__card-location-icon">
  <svg class="icon">
    <use href="images/icons.svg#icon-star" />
  </svg>
</span> 

Inside my images/icons.svg file I use the id="icon-star" file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <symbol id="icon-star" viewBox="0 -3.5 28 28" width="49" height="30">
        <path style="fill: inherit" d="M9.15316 5.40838C10.4198 3.13613 11.0531 2 12 2C12.9469 2 13.5802 3.13612
        14.8468 5.40837L15.1745 5.99623C15.5345 6.64193 15.7144 6.96479 15.9951 7.17781C16.2757 7.39083 16.6251 
        7.4699 17.3241 7.62805L17.9605 7.77203C20.4201 8.32856 21.65 8.60682 21.9426 9.54773C22.2352 10.4886 
        21.3968 11.4691 19.7199 13.4299L19.2861 13.9372C18.8096 14.4944 18.5713 14.773 18.4641 15.1177C18.357 
        15.4624 18.393 15.8341 18.465 16.5776L18.5306 17.2544C18.7841 19.8706 18.9109 21.1787 18.1449 21.7602C17.3788 
        22.3417 16.2273 21.8115 13.9243 20.7512L13.3285 20.4768C12.6741 20.1755 12.3469 20.0248 12 20.0248C11.6531 
        20.0248 11.3259 20.1755 10.6715 20.4768L10.0757 20.7512C7.77268 21.8115 6.62118 22.3417 5.85515 
        21.7602C5.08912 21.1787 5.21588 19.8706 5.4694 17.2544L5.53498 16.5776C5.60703 15.8341 5.64305 
        15.4624 5.53586 15.1177C5.42868 14.773 5.19043 14.4944 4.71392 13.9372L4.2801 13.4299C2.60325 11.4691 
        1.76482 10.4886 2.05742 9.54773C2.35002 8.60682 3.57986 8.32856 6.03954 7.77203L6.67589 7.62805C7.37485 
        7.4699 7.72433 7.39083 8.00494 7.17781C8.28555 6.96479 8.46553 6.64194 8.82547 5.99623L9.15316 5.40838Z" 
        stroke="inherit" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    </symbol>

Here is my CSS class for icon:
.icon {
    fill: currentColor;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;

    &:not(.icon--no-position) {
        position: relative;
        top: -0.075em;
    }
    
}

When I inspect the use element in my web inspector it has a size of 0 x 0. That's why the symbol is not shown. I don't understand the problem.
I tried to use the SVG code directly in my HTML (without use) the SVG is shown without any problems..
<span class="service__card-location-icon">
  <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 -3.5 28 28">
    <path d="M9.15316 5.40838C10.4198 3.13613 11.0531 2 12 2C12.9469 2 13.5802 3.13612 14.8468 5.40837L15.1745 5.99623C15.5345 6.64193 15.7144 6.96479 15.9951 7.17781C16.2757 7.39083 16.6251 7.4699 17.3241 7.62805L17.9605 7.77203C20.4201 8.32856 21.65 8.60682 21.9426 9.54773C22.2352 10.4886 21.3968 11.4691 19.7199 13.4299L19.2861 13.9372C18.8096 14.4944 18.5713 14.773 18.4641 15.1177C18.357 15.4624 18.393 15.8341 18.465 16.5776L18.5306 17.2544C18.7841 19.8706 18.9109 21.1787 18.1449 21.7602C17.3788 22.3417 16.2273 21.8115 13.9243 20.7512L13.3285 20.4768C12.6741 20.1755 12.3469 20.0248 12 20.0248C11.6531 20.0248 11.3259 20.1755 10.6715 20.4768L10.0757 20.7512C7.77268 21.8115 6.62118 22.3417 5.85515 21.7602C5.08912 21.1787 5.21588 19.8706 5.4694 17.2544L5.53498 16.5776C5.60703 15.8341 5.64305 15.4624 5.53586 15.1177C5.42868 14.773 5.19043 14.4944 4.71392 13.9372L4.2801 13.4299C2.60325 11.4691 1.76482 10.4886 2.05742 9.54773C2.35002 8.60682 3.57986 8.32856 6.03954 7.77203L6.67589 7.62805C7.37485 7.4699 7.72433 7.39083 8.00494 7.17781C8.28555 6.96479 8.46553 6.64194 8.82547 5.99623L9.15316 5.40838Z" stroke="inherit" stroke-width="1.5"/>
  </svg>
</span>


Could you add the error you are getting (image and text)?

Have you closed the  label after you load the symbol?

Are you sure, your path is correct? "images/icons.svg" It should work flawlessly provided you asset svg is on the same domain as your page. External use references are very strict in terms of cross origin access even with CORS headers access.

I found the error. I am working with Live-Server. In order to get it running it is necessary to completely restart the Live-Server.
